# SQL Table Transformation - using an "if" statement in the "Select" command to split text in a column into their own rows

Tags: sql, hana

I have a source date table in this format:

```
Year  Mon1              Mon2      ...      Mon12
2025  1110001110001101  0010111010110110
2024  000111011011101   0101101110110101
```

This is the source table. This is a calendar table, and each "1 or 0" in the Month column represents a day, and 1 is for days worked and 0 is for days not worked for each year based off of the US holiday Calendar

I am looking to transform this table into the following Format, as seen in image 2

```
Year  Month   Day  Working day
2025  01      01   0
2025  01      02   1
```

For the entire table.

Does anybody know of any way to accomplish this?

[image: This image is the source table]

[image: how the table needs to be transformed]

Comment: At the very least, you need to tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the input - the database is a SAP/HANA database, and I am querying using SQL rules from microsoft SQL

Answer (score 0):

Bottom Up Approach :

Step 1 : Form queries to extract individual Month Columns for a particular year

Step 2 : Apply Split_String `SPLIT_TO_TABLE` logic to convert columns to rows. Refer [this link](https://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/hana-database-builtin-sqlscript-library-string-functions.aspx)

Step 3 : Apply case statement for each of these column to row tables to identify if it is a working day or a non-working day.

Step 4 : `Union All` the result for every month.

Step 5 : Iterate this logic for all years.

Answer (score 0):

The source table mentioned is a **SAP factory calendar** table.
I have explained this a little bit more in detail in [Finding answers on workdays/](https://www.lbreddemann.org/finding-answers-on-workdays/).

As calendar calculations are rather common, SAP HANA comes with helper functions that can take the factory calendar table `TFACS` format and work with the data without the need for complicated transformations.

For the mentioned scenario, one can use the `WORKDAYS_BETWEEN()` function (see [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/d232c253d295101486a3dee449981b3f.html)).

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT
        GENERATED_period_start AS start_day,
        GENERATED_period_end AS end_day
    FROM 
        series_generate_date('INTERVAL 1 DAY', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01' )
)
SELECT 
    cal.start_day AS cal_day,
    DAYNAME( cal.start_day) day_name,
    workdays_between ('AU', cal.start_day, cal.end_day, 'SYSTEM') AS workday
    
FROM 
     calendar cal;

CAL_DAY   |DAY_NAME |WORKDAY|
----------|---------|-------|
2018-01-01|MONDAY   |      0|
2018-01-02|TUESDAY  |      1|
2018-01-03|WEDNESDAY|      1|
[...]
2018-12-28|FRIDAY   |      0|
2018-12-29|SATURDAY |      1|
2018-12-30|SUNDAY   |       | <-- date not maintained in TFACS
2018-12-31|MONDAY   |       | <--/
```

In my example, I have maintained table `TFACS` for the year 2018.
With the `calendar` common query I generate the dates for all days between January 1st 2018 and January 1st 2019.
For every day, the `WORKDAYS_BETWEEN()` function gets called for the current and the following day (`PERIOD_START` and `PERIOD_END` of the `SERIES_GENERATE_DATE` table function) to determine whether this was a working day or not.

If no entry in `TFACS` is found, the result of the function is empty.

Note, there is also a function called `ADD_WORKDAYS()` that is handy when the requirement is to not just tabulate the calendar against the workdays, but do calculations and taking the workdays into account.

Comment: Never knew this concept existed! So these functions works without explicitly referring to TFACS table?

Comment: The `WORKDAY`-functions take an optional parameter to specify the schema of the `TFACS` table to be used (see documentation).